# How to benefit from air-conditioning water

Tags: water, reuse, air-conditioning

I'm doing research on the water of the air conditioning, and a dissertation on how it could be collected and where it could be used. I already started by collecting some figures and I did some experiments such as (PH, TDS, EC). I mixed this water with water from a well and used it in planting.

What are other uses for water from air-conditioners?

Comment: How much water does an air-conditioner produce?

Comment: Since it's probably not drinking water, you can look up uses/treatment of greywater. Your water should be a lot cleaner than greywater, so you should be able to use it for cleaning (floors, possibly even laundry).

Comment: With very old air conditioners (and dehumdifiers) lead solder on the pipework was an issue, leading to recommendations to avoid using the condensate on food plants.

Comment: *some experiments such as (PH, TDS, EC)* Please [edit] your question and explain those terms.

Answer (score 4):

You certainly can use it as water to grow plants. But better not drinking it, since it can host bacteria in the long run.

There is good stuff about it here: http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2011/08/how_gross_is_the_water_that_drips_from_air_conditioners.html

It can also be linked here in the site: someone thought about filtering it before drinking - [Can you drink condensation water from air-con after treating it?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/3228/water-condensation-using-air-conditioners)

But anyway, this water wouldn't have any minerals in it, so no good for drinking for the every-day.